# Empty nested initializer list in C++

Tags: c++, initializer-list

Consider this piece of code:

```
struct S {
    float b;
    int a;    
};

int main() {
    S s{{{}}};
    return s.a;
}
```

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/CWTB4E)

**Clang 6.0.0** compiles this code, but shows a warning:

> *<source> warning: too many braces around scalar initializer [-Wmany-braces-around-scalar-init]*

**GCC 8.2** doesn't compile this code and reports an error:

> *<source>: In function 'int main()':
>   <source>:9:10: error: braces around scalar initializer for type 'float'*

Which one is correct? What does the specification say about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both compilers are correct.  Unless you violate a rule that says *no diagnostic required* the compiler should issue you a message.  Whether that message is a warning or an error is up to the implementation.  Normally you'll get a warning if it is something the compiler can still proceed with and an error when there is no way the compiler can continue.

Answer (score 1):

> What does the specification say about this?

[dcl.init.aggr/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.aggr#3):

> 3 When an aggregate is initialized by an initializer list as specified in [dcl.init.list], the elements of the initializer list are taken as initializers for the elements of the aggregate. The explicitly initialized elements of the aggregate are determined as follows:
>
> 3.1 If the initializer list is a designated-initializer-list, the aggregate shall be of class type, the identifier in each designator shall name a direct non-static data member of the class, and the explicitly initialized elements of the aggregate are the elements that are, or contain, those members.
>
> 3.2 If the initializer list is an initializer-list, the explicitly initialized elements of the aggregate are the first n elements of the aggregate, where n is the number of elements in the initializer list.
>
> 3.3 **Otherwise, the initializer list must be {}**, and there are no explicitly initialized elements.